# Jest - testing try/catch returning empty string

Tags: node.js, jestjs, nestjs

I have a nest.js application and I need to testing a http request, that if it fails needs to return an empty string

```
  async getUser(): Promise<any> {
    try {
      return await lastValueFrom(
        this.httpService.get('some endpoint')
        }).pipe(map(response => response.data));
      )
    } catch (error) {
       return '';
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to test it

```
  it('should test failed request', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(httpService, 'get').mockReturnValue(throwError(() => new Error('')))
    await expect(service.getUser()).toEqual('')
  })
```

I'm getting:

```
Expected: ""
Received: {}
```

Comment: Does this change if you `return await lastValueFrom(...)`?

Comment: I added that, but it doesn't change the output

Comment: instaed of `mockReturnValue`, try [`mockRejectedValue`](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrejectedvaluevalue)

Comment: @MicaelLevi wouldn't be necessary. The `httpService#get` method _returns_ a value, it doesn't resolve. It's an observable not a promise. That said, perhaps `of (new Error(''))` instead of `throwError()` would do here

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I tried to change to `mockReturnValue(() => of(new Error('')))` but it gives me the following: `is not assignable to parameter of type Observable<AxiosResponse<unknown, any>>`